# Cheating tar out of "Cannot change mode to rwxrwxrwx: No such file or directory"?

Tags: permissions, tar

I'm trying to build GCC 10, and in the end, I get a failure in `make install` (I'm trying to run `sudo checkinstall -D --install=no --fstrans=no` instead of `make install`, though, so I can build a .deb package). The failure is here:

```
...
/bin/bash /mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_source/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/../mkinstalldirs /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include
rm -rf /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed
mkdir /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed
chmod a+rx /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed
echo `${PWDCMD-pwd}`
/mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc
(cd `${PWDCMD-pwd}`/include ; \
 tar -cf - .; exit 0) | (cd /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include; tar xpf - )
(cd `${PWDCMD-pwd}`/include-fixed ; \
 tar -cf - .; exit 0) | (cd /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed; tar --ignore-failed-read -xpf - )
tar: ./python3.5: Cannot change mode to rwxrwxrwx: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Makefile:3861: recipe for target 'install-headers-tar' failed
make[2]: *** [install-headers-tar] Error 2
```

More specifically, I have `${PWDCMD-pwd}` resolving to /mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc; and then this part fails:

```
(cd `${PWDCMD-pwd}`/include-fixed ; \
 tar -cf - .; exit 0) | (cd /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed; tar --ignore-failed-read -xpf - )
tar: ./python3.5: Cannot change mode to rwxrwxrwx: No such file or directory
```

So, this piece wants to to enter `/mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc/include-fixed`, and copy the contents to `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed` using `tar`.

The source dir `/mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc/include-fixed` does exist and has contents:

```
$ ls -la  /mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc/include-fixed/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi pi  4096 Feb  2 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 pi pi 36864 Feb  3 01:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi  4096 Feb  2 06:26 arm-linux-gnueabihf
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi  6171 Feb  2 20:42 limits.h
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi pi  4096 Feb  2 06:26 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 pi pi    10 Feb  2 06:26 python3.5 -> python3.5m
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi pi  4096 Feb  2 06:26 python3.5m
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi   750 Feb  2 20:42 README
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi   330 Feb  2 06:26 syslimits.h
```

So, it can be seen that the file `./python3.5` which caused the "Cannot change mode to rwxrwxrwx" is present, and is in fact a symlink.

In fact, at this time, even the destination directory is somewhat populated - and at least the `./python3.5` symlink has been copied:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10.1.0/include-fixed/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb  3 01:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 pi   pi   4096 Feb  3 01:21 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Feb  2 06:26 arm-linux-gnueabihf
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi   6171 Feb  2 20:42 limits.h
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 01:21 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi     10 Feb  2 06:26 python3.5 -> python3.5m
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Feb  3 01:21 python3.5m
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi    750 Feb  2 20:42 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi   pi    330 Feb  2 06:26 syslimits.h
```

So, I guess I "just" have to persuade `tar` not to crash if it has problems with permission - and I thought I'd do that by using `tar --ignore-failed-read -xpf -` instead of the original `tar xpf -` in the `/mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc/Makefile`) - but clearly, from the above log, that doesn't work.

What can I do in this case to persuade `tar` not to crash here, so I can complete my `make install` (that is, `checkinstall`)?

Answer (score 0):

Crappy workaround, but - since the symlink is relative to source in its own folder, I just did:

```
mv  /mnt/loop/tmp/pi/gcc-10.1.0_build/gcc/include-fixed/python3.5 /tmp/
```

... to get rid of it - and this indeed passes. My intention was then to restore it in the target directory - but now I've got other errors ...